# OData Model v2 $expand makes infinite requests

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

My application uses an oData v2 model to connect to an SAP gateway.

All simple (element or aggregation) binding works well and as expected. I am facing the issue when binding an aggregation using `$expands` that the model makes infinite requests.

The url of the requests look always like `"ProductionOrderSet('0000011265361')/ProdOrdComponents?$skip=9&$top=6"` where `ProdOrdComponents` is the expanded Entity and the `$skip=9&$top=6` stays the same.

The JS code for binding looks like

```
this.getView().byId("idTest").bindAggregation("items", "backendData>ProdOrdComponents", new Tile({}));
```

So the xml view contains an `sap.m.VBox` with the id `"idTest"`. The binding uses a template to generate the new controls for the aggregation.

Comment: There is no $expand anywhere in your URL. You are just following the association to ProdOrdComponents, i.e. the returned entity is a list of ProdOrdComponents. In case of a real $expand, the returned entity would be the ProductionOrder with all ProdOrderComponents contained (expanded) inline.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: @user2808624, gave the hint.

The `?$expand=ProdOrdComponents` was part of the binding as string, which is obviously not correct.

Therefore the model didn't recognise the connection from `ProductionOrderSet` to `ProdOrdComponents` so it loaded all the data on itself.

After setting the parameter correctly as `parameters: {expand:'ProdOrdComponents'}` it works.